# Input validation for characters use only, in C++

Tags: c++, validation

How do I validate that the user have entered only characters and not numbers?

```
char name[20];
cin.getline(name, 20);

If(!cin) {
 cerr<<"ERROR"<<endl;
 cin.clear();
}
```

Comment: Use std::isdigit http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: Also, use `std::string` instead of arrays of characters.

Comment: Thank you! I'm afraid that the moodle's program checker will not recognize it though.

Comment: How do i limit string to a specific amount of chars? Using getline?